# How to uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, installation

How to uninstall  SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

ControlPanel's "Uninstall or change programs" (in Windows 7 Prof) gives a row of entries:

[image]

while [internet search results always tell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909953): "click Microsoft SQL Server 2005, and then click Change"

UPDATE (commenting [Shawn Melton's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55447/28279)):

Upon choosing " "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)"--> Uninstall/Change, I observe:

[image]

and after choosing "Remove", "Setup Support Rules" without any SSMS or continuation option:

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will select "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)"

[image]

Upon loading of the setup wizard, you will select the instance for SQL Server 2012. The next screen you check the shared component you want to remove.

[image]