# Why does SQL Server Management Studio crash?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, installation

When I open SSMS I get this message:

> SSMS - SQL Server Management Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

What can I do?

[image]

The issue persists after a reboot and I do not have any add-ins installed.

This is SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS running on Windows XP.

SSMS was running without errors before on this machine.

SSMS was installed from SQL Server package not alone. Is it recommended to reinstall the package? Or how to install SSMS alone?

The same issue occurs for all users.

Comment: It would help us assist you if you could click on the underlined "click here" link in the error message and post the contents thereof.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error, you should understand the actual error which is not displayed in the screenshot that you've provided in your question. You can view the actual error by reading the application events within the event viewer when the error occurs.

1. Start by writing down the timestamp when the error happens.
2. Open Event Viewer
3. View the application logs and match the error message with the timestamp when the error occurred.

It's pretty common knowledge that Microsoft displays friendly errors to users when errors occur by default which generally leads the end user to questions that cant be answered, friendly error messages only complicate questions. You need to view the source. Feel free to ask your question again so that a professional can provide you a better professional response from a professionally written question with all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from comments on the question.*</sub>

[TomV](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39384/tom-v): Make sure you have applied the latest Service Pack and Cumulative Updates.

[Jens W.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/35264/jens-w): Check if it still crashes if you use it with another user (clean profile).

[swasheck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4490/swasheck): Check the Windows event log for clues.

[Aaron Bertrand ♦](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand): Cumulative Update (CU) and other servicing terms are explained in [KB #935897.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/935897)

Me: See the following question and answer for how to uninstall the Management Tools. Once that is done, you can use much the same procedure to install Management Tools again:

[How to uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 2012?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55446/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: Just Add - Windows XP. it possible some reason still have it on industrial PC, but for SSMS - long time ago need migrate for 7. XP was good system, but save it on PC - it like deadlock in SQL Server - any new update (like NET for SSMS) need some other updates, but this updates not work on proper  XP. It possible search and search for new errors, but more right - install SSMS on PC with at least Windows 7. As well as SSMS - one of the last version. SSMS 2014 excellent work with SQL Server 2008